Проблема запуска react native app
Всем доброго дня.
У меня существует проблема запуска моего react-native-app
Я регулярно получаю ошибку будто у меня нет доступа к определенным действиям.
Как я уже нагуглил вся проблема заключается в том, что CocaPods не имеет прав на запись.
Это основная проблема, я уже пытаюсь нагуглить вторые сутки, ищу помощи у вас коллеги. Раннее с реакт нейтив не работал, всегда делал десктпные версии.


 #  from /Users/frontendsamuraj/Desktop/webstorm/newnative/AwesomeProject/ios/Podfile:20
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_react_native!(
 #      :path => config[:reactNativePath],
 #  -------------------------------------------

[!] [Codegen] warn: using experimental new codegen integration



Честно даже не знаю уже что вам можно отправить, возможно совместными усилиями решим данную проблему

Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Adding script_phases to React-Codegen.
[!] Invalid Podfile file: [!] /bin/mkdir -p ./build/generated/ios
mkdir: ./build: Permission denied
.

error Failed to build ios project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '65'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'AwesomeProject.xcodeproj'.
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project AwesomeProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=B334CAD1-C94A-4D44-B9D1-A06A8CC74DEA
User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
Prepare packages
